# Should language tags be used for IDE questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have a question about an Eclipse feature. Is it appropriate to include the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag even though the question isn't about Java per se?

Question in question: [Search modified files in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769110/search-modified-files-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Use tags to represent what you're *actually* asking about.  If you're asking about an Eclipse feature, the [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) tag would be sufficient.  For your given example, that's entirely language-agnostic and only has to do with the IDE, so I would be very confused if I saw [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) in that question at all.

Comment: Yeah I figured. It's frustrating though, because I suspect a lot of people with expertise in Eclipse don't actively follow that tag.

Comment: It's half my frustration from being in Java and IntelliJ.  Yes, these often go hand-in-hand, but I'm not a fan of seeing a Java question *also* tagged with its IDE.  The reverse applies too; if you're just asking a question about the tool and not what you're doing *in* the tool, then asking about the tool is fine.

Comment: Conversely, it could be the case that a Java dev *happens* to use Eclipse, not that they're equipped to answer questions about it.  I'd rather the actual experts that followed the Eclipse tag take a look at a question like that rather than someone who's going to take a guess.